# Issue getting Rss feed ionic 2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, rss

I'm having some trouble trying to parse simple `rss feed` using Ionic Framework 2. When I run the code I'm not getting any feed data. 
Could you help me?

`rss-service.ts`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RssService {

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    load() {

        return Observable.create(s => {

        this.http.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20title%2Clink%2Cdescription%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fraymondcamdensblog%3Fformat%3Dxml%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=').subscribe(res => {
            console.log('in sub');
            console.dir(s);
           var result = res.json().query.results.item;
            result.forEach(i=>s.next(i));
            s.complete();

        });

      });
 }
}
```

`home.html` - `home.ts`

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title text-center>
            App Name
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-list inset>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let entry of entries" (click)="openPage(entry)">{{entry.title}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>

|------------------------------------------------------------|

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RssService } from '../../providers/rss-service/rss-service';
import { DetailPage } from '../detail-page/detail-page';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [RssService],

})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public rssService:RssService, public nav:NavController) {

      this.nav = nav;
      var entries = [];
      this.rssService.load().subscribe(
          data => {
              entries = data;
          }
      );

   }

  openPage(entry) {
      console.log('open page called with '+ entry.title);
      this.nav.push(DetailPage, {selectedEntry:entry});
  }

}
```

`detail-page.html` - `detail-page.ts`

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
    <ion-title>{{entry.title}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="detail-page">
    <div [innerHTML]="entry.description"></div>
</ion-content>

|---------------------------------------------|

import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'detail-page',
    templateUrl: 'detail-page.html'
})
export class DetailPage {
    constructor(public nav: NavController, navParams:NavParams) {
        console.log('run');
        this.nav = nav;
        var entry = navParams.get('selectedEntry');
        console.log('my entry is '+ entry.title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the code comments.

Try with

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class RssService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RssService Provider');
  }

  load() {

        return Observable.create(s => {

        this.http.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20title%2Clink%2Cdescription%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fraymondcamdensblog%3Fformat%3Dxml%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=')
        .map(res => res.json()) /* map res obj to json obj */ 
        .subscribe(data => {
           console.log(data);
           var items = data.query.results.item;
           items.forEach(i=>s.next(i));
           s.complete();
        });
      });
 }

}
```

and

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RssService } from '../../providers/rss-service';
import { DetailPage } from '../detail/detail';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {

  public entries: any  = []; /* this needs to be class level variable */

  constructor(public rssService:RssService, public nav:NavController) {    
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
      this.rssService.load().subscribe(
          data => {
              this.entries.push(data); /* push retrieved data into the array */
          }
      );
  } 

  openPage(entry) {
      console.log('open page called with '+ entry.title);
      this.nav.push(DetailPage, {selectedEntry:entry});
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pal, it works!! :) Now I'm getting an error when I click on an item but eventually I'll post another question